# Single incorrect glyph when exported to SVG at smaller font size (Illustrator CC)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, svg, export

I'm trying to export an SVG for web use from Illustrator and for some reason the `o` in this font family (Bilo) refuses to play nicely.

This is what it looks like inside of AI. The larger text is 22px, the smaller text is 17px. Nothing else has been changed. [image: Inside of AI]

This is what it looks like on the Adobe Font site when you preview it at 17px. [image: Adobe Font preview at 17px]

And this is what it looks like when I export an SVG from AI. [image: Exported SVG]

The SVG font setting in the image above is set to Convert to Outlines. I've tried

- Every combination of SVG export settings (Saving with Font set to SVG works, but not in Safari, so that's no good.)
- I've also tried creating outlines before saving
- Using Object > Expand with both Object and Fill checked.

This wonky `o` just keeps coming back to haunt me. It happens with all of the Bilo font weights.

It's activated via the built-in Adobe Fonts connector in AI - is there maybe an issue with the font itself?

Comment: hmm . . I get the same, can't find a way to fix it with "Export as", but "Save as" SVG seems to work just fine.  Perhaps this is a bug. If so, best t to contact Adobe about it.

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm getting the same issue using the Save As dialog - do you mind sharing what settings you used to get past it? (And what font size? Seems to only happen with smaller sizing regardless of export format for me.)

Comment: All I did was File > Save As, then choose SVG as file type, set to SVG 1.1, Type to "Convert to outlines". Font sizes were the same as yours 17px. Align to pixel grid disabled. [Here's the SVG](https://svgshare.com/i/NQH.svg). My document also had "Align art to pixel grid" disabled. Illustrator version 22.1

Comment: Snap! That worked! I've never used that save method for SVG before, didn't even think to try it. Miraculous. Thanks for replying, I really appreciate it. I did end up sending a video to Adobe Support since it does seem that the other "normal" methods of SVG export have a problem somewhere, so we'll say what they say in a day or so. I'll update here for posterity. Thanks again @BillyKerr.

Comment: The "Save as" SVG method is legacy, and "Export As" is newer, so that might be why the results are different.